# Angular JS with specific select checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

```
<body ng-app="workApp">
<div ng-controller="firstClaimController">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="sbcfunction()"> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="sbcfunction()"> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="sbcfunction()"> Option 3
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="sbcfunction()"> Option 4

            {{myValue}}
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var claimController = angular.module('workApp', []); 
        claimController.controller('firstClaimController', function($scope){
    // Test the controller whether it works
        $scope.myValue = "asdf";
    // 
            $scope.sbcfunction = function () {

            };
    });
    </script>
```

The above is my code and i got 4 checkboxes. The aim is Option 1 is single select and Options 2-4 are multi-select. If Option 1 is selected, Option 2-4 should be deselected automatically. If Option 2-4 are selected Option 1 should be deselected.

Looking for a better solution with angularjs.

Comment: Hi @Alaksandar! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Does my answer solve your question? If it does you should mark it as accepted, if it doesn't could you please explain me how can I make it better? Thanks!

Comment: @Josep Thanks for your support. I shall work it out and keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-change`.

## Without Functions

This should work in the way that you want it to:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="option1" ng-change="multiOption1=multiOption1&&!option1;multiOption2=multiOption2&&!option1;multiOption3=multiOption3&&!option1"> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="multiOption1" value="option2" ng-change="option1=!(multiOption1||multiOption2||multiOption3)"> Option 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="multiOption2" value="option3" ng-change="option1=!(multiOption1||multiOption2||multiOption3)"> Option 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="multiOption3" value="option4" ng-change="option1=!(multiOption1||multiOption2||multiOption3)"> Option 4</label>
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qgoe5m7p/2/)

## With Functions

If you prefer to use functions, you can do it like this:

In your controller add this:

```
$scope.option1=true;
$scope.option1Changed=function(){
    $scope.multiOption1=$scope.multiOption1&&!$scope.option1;
    $scope.multiOption2=$scope.multiOption2&&!$scope.option1;
    $scope.multiOption3=$scope.multiOption3&&!$scope.option1;
}
$scope.multiOptionsChanged=function(){
    $scope.option1=!($scope.multiOption1||$scope.multiOption2||$scope.multiOption3);
}
```

And in your view do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="option1" ng-change="option1Changed()"> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="multiOption1" value="option2" ng-change="multiOptionsChanged()"> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="multiOption2" value="option3" ng-change="multiOptionsChanged()"> Option 3
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="multiOption3" value="option4" ng-change="multiOptionsChanged()"> Option 4
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qgoe5m7p/3/)

Comment: Josep, looks like in Your example You can't do multi-select with options 2-4.

Comment: oh! sorry give me a sec to fix it! you are right! I thought that you wanted them to be radio buttons! my bad!